# SoapUI: have multiple expected results in one assertion

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui, assertions

Is there a way to have multiple expected results in one assertion for one test step.

Declare:

`declare namespace b="base"; //b:policies/b:policy/b:total-premium`

Expected Result:

`7.362*`

XML Assertion code:

```
<con:assertion type="XPath Match" id="" name="XPath Match">                                             
<con:configuration>                                             
<path>                                              
declare namespace b="base"; //b:policies/b:policy/b:total-premium                                               
</path>                                             
<content>7.362*</content>                                               
<allowWildcards>true</allowWildcards>                                               
<ignoreNamspaceDifferences>false</ignoreNamspaceDifferences>                                                
<ignoreComments>false</ignoreComments>                                              
</con:configuration>                                                
</con:assertion>                                                
<con:credentials>                                               
<con:authType>No Authorization</con:authType>                                               
</con:credentials>                                              
<con:jmsConfig JMSDeliveryMode="PERSISTENT"/>                                               
<con:jmsPropertyConfig/>                                                
<con:wsaConfig mustUnderstand="NONE" version="200508" action="" addDefaultTo="true"/>
```

What I would like SoapUI to do is compare the value from `total-premium` to the values of `7.362*`, `6.994*`, and `7.730*` for this specific test step and if any of them passes the test step passes.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible way to do so is to use `Script assertion` instead of `Xpath match assertion`.

In the `Script assertion` you can parse the response, get the node values and compare against the list of the possible values, something like:

```
// get the xml response
def response = messageExchange.getResponseContent() 
// parse it
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
// find your node by name
def node = xml.'**'.find { it.name() == 'total-premium' }
// assert against the possible values
assert ['7.362*','6.994*','7.730*'].contains(node.toString())
```

**Update**

I misunderstood your question at first I think that you want to check exactly `7.362*`, and really the wildcard is for any digits, excuse me. Then you can use a regex with `matches()` method to check if you value starts with some of the desired values:

```
// get the xml response
def response = messageExchange.getResponseContent() 
// parse it
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
// find your node by name
def node = xml.'**'.find { it.name() == 'total-premium' }
// assert 
assert node.toString().matches("(7.362|6.994|7.730)\\d*")
```

Comment: I get this error: `assert ['7.36*','6.99*','7.73*'].contains(node.toString()) | | | false | 6.9943104 6.9943104` is that because it trying to find the exact string of `6.9943104`. if so, how do i get it to be a wildcard?

Comment: One way would be to use regex?

Comment: Amazing Thank you. Made my life so much easier :)

Comment: @Ross nice to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer XPath over Groovy scripting, you can still use a simple XPath expression:

```
declare namespace b="base";

starts-with(//b:policies/b:policy/b:total-premium, '7.362') or 
starts-with(//b:policies/b:policy/b:total-premium, '6.994') or 
starts-with(//b:policies/b:policy/b:total-premium, '7.730')
```

The expected result is then *true*.

With XPath you can use functions and operators as in other programming languages.

Comment: Instead of multiple, a list of values can be used with `|`?